# Can I save a LUKS (or other encryption) passphrase or key in the TPM?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, tpm

The spec is rather complex. The software is rather sensitive, so I keep it on an encrypted volume. My assumption was SecureBoot with my own Platform Key to ensure only my signed boot-loader runs, and then keep the primary disk (or even just the data with the software) encrypted.

The problem, of course, is the decryption key. Can I store (bind or seal) it in the TPM, thus making it decryptable *only* on this platform?

With SecureBoot ensuring only my unmodified boot is running, my boot reading the decryption key from TPM, and some form of sensor that causes the firmware to be wiped (or the TPM to be reset) if opened, I should have a moderately secure box. This won't stop a government actor, but it should stop casual cracking.

Can I use the TPM for this? How would I go about doing it?

Comment: Could you explain your first couple sentences a little better? I'm not well versed in this field by any means, but I find it a bit ambiguous.

Comment: I figured it out. Took lots of reading the specs and FAQ, but I did get it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes. Here is my design.

- SecureBoot enabled
- PK and all other keys replaced with my own keys *only*
- UEFI protected by impossibly long password to prevent unauthorized changes
- Boot disk has a small grub bootloader partition that is unencrypted
- Boot .uefi file is digitally signed by my private key
- Boot .uefi is configured to decrypt LUKS-encrypted other partition on disk, retrieving key from TPM
- Key is loaded into TPM to match exact current state of ROM+UEFI+boot partition+chassis closed alert not set off+peripherals+grub

This way, only my OS will load, if you make even the slightest change you cannot retrieve the decryption key (because the hashes will not match).

Comment: Would resetting a tpm affect a passwordless sign in? Or resetting the TPM make it impossible to decrypt the volume (save for Quantum, etc.)?